# Can you access the user.config file from multiple applications?

Tags: .net

I currently have two projects, lets call them "Project1" and "Project2".  Both are Console applications.

Project1 has settings like "dbName", "dbServer", etc... that are all stored in the user.config file.  This is the config file that is stored per user.

Is it possible to access the user.config file from Project1 when I start Project2? Meaning I can get access to the "dbName", "dbServer", etc.. within Project2?

Thanks!

Comment: I've done lots of research, but haven't found anything that works.